# How can we write a JUnit test in Java for Length()>255 which takes substring(0,255)

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

Suppose

```
getMethod = "String"
getMethod.length()>255 ? getMethod.substring(0,255) : getMethod;
```

Can anyone please suggest how can i write junits test for the above scenario.

I have tried manually setting of “String” length of 255 characters and assertEquals() method.

But iam wondering whether there are any other ways to write if the string value is “32000”?

Comment: don't show a vague "scenario", show a method you intend to test

Comment: taskBuild.getString().length() > 255 ? taskBuild.getString().substring(0, 255) : taskBuild.getString();

Comment: the actual method, in the question, not another vague bit in a comment.

Comment: Can you post the complete source code of the method/class you want to test? You can create a String with a given length by calling `String str = new String(new char[255]));` but I'm not sure if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

In the following solution, I used JUnit5 to write unit tests. I created 3 scenario for the method to be tested.

1. Should return given value
2. Should return substring value
3. Should return NullPointerException (You should handle this exception in the method but I leave it like this)

```java
package com.example.springdemo;

import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;


@SpringBootTest
public class DemoTest {

    @Test
    public void theMethod_ShouldReturnGivenValue() {
        String expected = "hello";
        String actual = theMethod(expected);

        Assertions.assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected);
    }

    @Test
    public void theMethod_ShouldReturnSubstringValue() {
        String value = "A".repeat(256);

        String actual = theMethod(value);
        String expected = "A".repeat(255);

        Assertions.assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected);
    }

    @Test
    public void theMethod_ShouldReturnNullPointerException() {
        String value = null;

        org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows(NullPointerException.class, () -> {
            theMethod(value);
        });
    }

    private String theMethod(String value) {
        String result = value.length() > 255 ? value.substring(0, 255) : value;
        return result;
    }
}
```